# Django uploadify Model Foreignkey

Tags: django, file-upload, uploadify

Hi I'm relatively new to Django. I'm creating an application, that allows users to upload imagegallries:

the important part of my models looks like this:

```
class location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 15)

class gallery(models.Model):
    location_id = models.ForeignKey(location)
    date = models.CharField(max_length = 15)

class Image(models.Model):
    location_id = models.ForeignKey(location)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    image = ImageField(upload_to='songs')

class AuthKey(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=60)
```

my view looks like this:

```
def myFileHandler(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for field_name in request.FILES:
            loc = request.POST['location']
            date = request.POST['date']
            if location.objects.filter(name=str(loc)):
                for l in location.objects.filter(name=str(loc)):
                    id = l.id
            gal = gallery(location_id=1, date='12/23/2009')
            gal.save()
        return HttpResponse("ok", mimetype="text/plain")
    else:
        return render_to_response('gallery_upload.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

the additional post data (loc/date) is sent via uploadify. Everything works fine, but when i try to save the model "gal" it doesn't work. If I test it with the location model instead of the gallery model it works. If I delete the foreignkey from the gallery model it also works, so it seems to be a problem with the foreign key field. I hope one of you guys has a solution for this.

Comment: First, always name classes in CamelCase, i.e. `Location` not `location`. Second, don't name foreign keys as "foo_id". Django automatically appends "_id" to the field name in the database, so you actually end up with "foo_id_id".

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
gal = Gallery.objects.create(location=location, date='12/12/2012')
```

instead of

```
gal = gallery(location_id=1, date='12/23/2009')
gal.save()
```

You seem to get messed up with location_id filed which is not actually an ID but object.

Comment: @Chris Patt: You're right. Now it works. Stupid beginners mistake.

Comment: Your solution works to, but I overwrote the models save method so I need to call it.